# Adding footer to Vuetify's list/menu/combobox

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I am trying to insert footer to the Vuetify's list or menu or combobox. They all are pretty same. I tried every possibe css solution I could without solution.

This is what I want but I want the bottom button to be statically visible at the bottom even if scrolling:

[image]

Regular fixed css solution do not work no matter on what element I do apply styles.

This is the combobox I am trying to implement it to:

```html
<v-combobox
    style="min-width: 260px;"
    dense
    :value="item.description"
    :items="products"
    item-text="name"
    item-value="id"
    :error-messages="item.description_error"
    :filter="filter_products"
    @input="product_selected"
    ref="description">
    <template
        slot="item"
        slot-scope="{ index, item, parent }">
        <v-list-tile-content v-if="!item.footer">{{ item.name }}</v-list-tile-content>
        <v-btn v-else flat dark small style="padding-left:0!important;margin-left:0!important;display:table-row;width:100%"
           color="primary"
           depressed
           :ripple="false"
           @click.stop="add_new_product"><v-icon left>add_box</v-icon>{{ item.footer }}</v-btn>
    </template>
</v-combobox>
```

Also tried using v-menu and v-list

```html
<v-menu max-height="250px">
    <v-text-field label="Hello" slot="activator"></v-text-field>
    <v-list>
        <v-list-tile v-for="item in 10">hello</v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
    <p style="position: fixed; bottom: 0;">IUWHEGIuiHWEGIUHGIWUEHGIUWHEGIUHWEIUG</p>
</v-menu>
```

Comment: I made something similar earlier https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJKVmK Not sure if it's alright? Is that what you meant? You forgot to provide a minimum codepen example, so I just skimmed.

Comment: @Traxo your version doee the same as mine. It is hidden by default in your version. I want it to be visible.

Comment: What do you mean? Footer is always visible in my codepen (after you open the menu), even when scrolling. At least in chrome? Maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Yep, it worked pretty much perfectly, just what I wanted. I opened it first on mobile, thats why I thought that it is the same.

Comment: You probably want something like this tho if possible https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zJoZwd
I'm not sure why I went for my first example initially, I think because combobox et al use `v-list-tile` as templates (slots) by default? Thus you can't add div at the same level as list, only new items? Hah, can't remember. I'll look into it more later if someone doesn't provide normal solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wEpMGB)

We need to add `max-height` and `overflow: auto` to the `v-list` element so that we can scroll the list, and not the whole menu.
Add "footer" to the bottom of the `v-menu` and it should work as expected.
And just wrap it inside the `v-card` for example so that menu is not transparent.

```
<v-menu v-model="menu" offset-y>
  <v-btn slot="activator">Menu</v-btn>
  <v-card>
    <v-list class="custom-list">
      <v-list-tile v-for="item in items"></v-list-tile>
    </v-list>
    <v-divider></v-divider>
    <div class="pa-1" @click.stop="">
      <v-btn flat dark small color="primary" depressed :ripple="false">
        <v-icon left>add_box</v-icon>
          footer button
      </v-btn>
    </div>
  </v-card>
</v-menu>
```

css

```
.custom-list {
  max-height:200px; 
  overflow: auto;
}
```

We can use `@click.stop=""` to prevent it from closing the menu.